# I cannot find my PDT configuration on PayPal anymore

Tags: paypal, paypal-pdt

I cannot find my PDT configuration on PayPal anymore.  I find docs that reference a Website Payment Preferences that I cannot find.

help!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should take you straight to it:  https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments

Long way is to log in, click on Profile, then Profile and Settings, then My Selling Tools, then Website Preferences.

Comment: I missed it in all the grey text.